# Load shared library that uses another shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mono, shared-libraries

I'm Linux rookie and I'm trying to move my library from windows to Linux. It is native binary (mylib.so), but it will be loaded by mono ( [DllImport()] ). I'm using a pcre (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) in this library. When my .NET executable tries to load mylib.so it throws exception (lib not found). When I set `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug`. I says that my library is found, but pcre library is not.

I've tried to to load it dynamically (`dlopen(), dlsym()`). When I build executable version of my library linking it with dl (-ldl) it works fine. But when I load it from mono I got SIGSEGV.

I create this library like (for version with dl):

```
g++ -fPIC -c *.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so.1.1 -ldl -o libmylib.so.1.1 *.o
```

I've create simple test program that link against `mylib.so and dl` (-l:libmylib.so.1.1 -ldl) and it works.

I think I need to force mylib to link with dl (or directly with pcre), but I don't know how. (I hope it's possible)

All what I want is to create library that use pcre and work under mono.

Comment: The pcre lib is within the search dirs for the loader, yeah? ldconfig -v shows it?

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly linked your library: if it uses libpcre you must link it, too, with the -lpcre option.